# SQL Server : format 700 as time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've run an import which has updated many records in my `tblRota.StartTime` and `tblRota.EndTime` in the format 900 and 1700.

How can I reformat these to 09:00 and 17:00?

The datatypes of both columns is `varchar`.

Thank you.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  Do you want them as an actual `time` datatype?  Or just formatted as `00:00` chars?  You really should just be using the correct data type to begin with, assuming you have control of the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this query:

```
select stuff(right('0' + replace([StartTime], ':', ''), 4), 3, 0, ':'),
       stuff(right('0' + replace([EndTime], ':', ''), 4), 3, 0, ':')
from [tblRota]
```

The steps are:

1. Remove the `:`: `replace([StartTime], ':', '')`
2. Get the time on 4 digits: `right('0' + <3Or4DigitTime>, 4)`
3. Insert the `:`: `stuff(<4DigitTime>, 3, 0, ':')`

Comment: This works okay, but some are formatted correctly already and they appear such as 8::00 if they were correct to begin with. How can I change it to ignore correct ones?

Comment: @JoshCooper - That was not specified in the specs :) => Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use some string manipulation:

```
UPDATE tblRota
SET StartTime = LEFT(RIGHT('0'+StartTime , 4),2)+':'+RIGHT(StartTime ,2),
    EndTime = LEFT(RIGHT('0'+EndTime , 4),2)+':'+RIGHT(EndTime ,2)
```

Comment: This works okay, but some are formatted correctly already and they appear such as 8::00 if they were correct to begin with. How can I change it to ignore correct ones?